# Android notifications not expanded when app in background

Tags: android, firebase, background, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send notifications with FCM, it works as expected but i'm facing two different behaviours that I want to deal with because I'm using bigtextstyle and an action:

First case: App in foreground,
onReceiveMessage works as expected and notification is shown correctly

[image: Case 1]

Second Case: App killed or in background, 
the documentation says that messages are not handled in the onReceiveMessage event, and the layout of the notification is not the bigtextstyle one:

[image: Case 2]

I tried to find a way for showing the desired layout, but nothing is working, they said that data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of the launcher Activity!

So, what I want, is to show the same notification layout in the two cases, because some time I use the notification to trigger a call or to open a link in a browser not to open the app itself.

I sent my messages from Firebase Console as shown :
[image: Firebase console]

and here's the function that notify :

```
    private void notifyMe(RemoteMessage rm){
    String title = "";
    String body = "";
    String phone = "";
    String link = "";
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent iCall;
    PendingIntent pintCall = null;
    Intent notificationIntent = null;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    notificationManager =  (NotificationManager)FirebaseMessagingService.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (rm.getNotification() != null) {
        title = rm.getNotification().getTitle();
        body = rm.getNotification().getBody();
    }

    if (rm.getData().size() > 0) {
        phone = rm.getData().get("phone");
        link = rm.getData().get("link");

        if(link.contains("http://")){
            notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link));
        }else{
            notificationIntent = new Intent(FirebaseMessagingService.this, MainActivity.class);
        }

        if(phone.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            iCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
            pintCall = PendingIntent.getActivity(FirebaseMessagingService.this, 0, iCall, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }

    }

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    PendingIntent pint = PendingIntent.getActivity(FirebaseMessagingService.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setWhen(time)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(pint);


    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigtext =  new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();

    bigtext.setBigContentTitle(title);
    bigtext.bigText(body);

    mBuilder.setStyle(bigtext);

    if(!phone.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        mBuilder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call, "Call me!", pintCall);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Someone has a path on how to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Notifications console sends so-called "notification messages". When your app is not in the foreground, these notifications messages are handled by the system itself and automatically displayed in the notification tray in the format you're seeing. When the user clicks this notification, the app is activated.

To ensure the message always gets delivered to your `onReceiveMessage` method, use "data messages".

For a great explanation, see the [documentation on the different message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

Comment: You mean that I must build my own server and manage registration and sending there ?

Comment: Sending data messages is at the moment only possible through Firebase Cloud Messaging, not through Firebase Notifications. FCM requires that your code specify your server key, which (as the name hints at) should only be used in a trusted process on a server.

Comment: Frank, I need to talk to my server guy but I'm sure we are always sending "data message" types. When my app is in the background it seems my pending intents are all ignored and the notification object opens into my launcher activity. additionally, it uses my full color icon, which I specifically set to grey scale in my onReceive. Some forum threads say this is a bug of firebase, but you are suggesting that there is a way around it by merely setting a 'data message' type?